# Users cannot find the way to key in information during registration

Tags: website-design, forms, registration

Many users cannot find the way to key in information during registration.

With a tracking script, we can see that users just click other places of page rather than the labels or fields of the form to continue.

We consider HTML5 to implement an auto-focus feature making users able to type without selecting fields, but not all browsers support this feature.
However actually many services don't use this feature.
(e.g. https://www.evernote.com/Registration.action).

**Updated**

Take one user for example, he clicks 20 times on the page and the action is valid in 10 times, that is, he just types in to continue. However, he just keeps clicking and finally left.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

[image: registraion form]

Comment: *"They just cilck labels of form.."* this is what the "for" attribute on labels is for, you should be able to click the label to access the field: https://jsfiddle.net/9pw8hyd0/

Comment: @DasBeasto, thank you for your reply. Just make a correction, the form support what you mention indeed. And with tracking script, we can see that users click other places of the page rather than labels or fields of the form.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "he clicks 20 times on the page and the action is valid in 10 times"?

Comment: @maxathousand, thank you for your reply. It means that the user has already selected the textfield and he can type information correctly if he wanted with 50% chance (10/20).

Comment: Are you sure it is humans having the problem or could it be bots?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thank you for your reply. No, we can't ensure it is human. But why do bots do this?

Comment: @Jun Because there are all different types of Bots collecting informations on the internet. This could be easily JS bug on your site, bug with Analytics software, or just false reading of the analytics / tracking script.

Answer (score 1):

With these few information, I can see some reasons:

- They don't want to register.
- They are trying to find other information rather than fill forms.
- Could not be a human clicking, like Andrew Morton said.
- Sometimes I click in ads on the web and go directly to the registration page and I never register because I want to confirm what is that before doing some action.
- It was obvious with the user, what they needed to do?

**Please, insert some prints of full screen and a bit more information about your personas, maybe I can help more. And please, tell what's happens before and after this step.**